# Unable to clear autocomplete value once selected in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, autocomplete

I am using knockout-jqautocomplete plugin in one of my projects. When ever i select a value in autocomplete i check whether the other array i am maintaing already has the value . If yes i do nothing, else i add the selected value to the array. 
Once i click/select the value , the selected value is populated in the autocomplete text box. But i do not want this to happen.

Once i click it i just need it to call the required function to check if it already exists or not and clear the auto complete value. But for some reason the i am not able to clear the autocomplete value.

Please find the jsfiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kumarr/qy0dkbdp/2/

Would appreciate any help

```
var ViewModel = function() {
var self = this;
this.templateValue = ko.observable();

this.remoteData = ko.observableArray([{
        id: 1,
        name: "one",
        description: "one description"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "two",
        description: "two description"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "three",
        description: "three description"
    }]);


this.ownerList = ko.observableArray([]);






this.addOwners = function (owner) {
    var exists = false;


        for (var o in self.ownerList()) {
            var temp = self.ownerList()[o];
            if (temp.id === owner.id) {
                exists = true;
            }
        }

        if (exists === false) {
            self.ownerList.push({
                "id": owner.id,
                "name": owner.name
            });
        }
        self.templateValue('');        


}

};


ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

my html

```
<input data-bind="jqAuto: { source: remoteData, value: templateValue, inputProp: 'name', template: 'itemTmpl'  }" />

<div data-bind="foreach:ownerList">
  <div data-bind="text:name">
  </div>
</div>


<script id="itemTmpl" type="text/html">
  <a>
    <strong data-bind="text: id,click:$root.addOwners"></strong>
    <em data-bind="text: name,click:$root.addOwners"></em>
  </a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than adding a `click` binding in your template, I think that an approach that could work better for you in this scenario is to subscribe to the `templateValue` observable. Whenever it is updated, you can run your logic, push to your observableArray, if necessary, and finally clear the value.

You set up a subscription like:

```
this.templateValue.subscribe(this.addOwners);
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/brpd63r8/

Comment: The solution worked but i had to make a condition check in my addowners method to check if the value(owner) is not empty and perform the operation else the empty value was added to my array the first time .  Hence i tried adding only the settimeout method alone and it worked.